# Show that this equation has no solution in $\Bbb{R}$ without doing calculation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that this equation has no solution in $\Bbb{R}$ without doing calculation (that is, without finding the roots of the equation): $$2x^4+7x^2+1=0$$

How can I do it? I have no clue. Can you help me please.

Comment: @egreg You can just type: `\Bbb{R}` instead of the long `\mathbb{R}`.

Comment: @Adobe The recommended LaTeX command is `\mathbb`, while `\Bbb` has been declared obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

The left hand side is always greater or equal to $1$ (why? What do you know about square numbers and $4^{\text{th}}$ power if $x$ is real?)

Comment: @IanMateus think you deserve a disciplined badge for deleting your own answer!

Answer (score 3):

First, rearrange the equation to get: $2x^4+7x^2=-1$

Then, notice that: $x^4 \geqslant 0$ and $x^2\geqslant 0$ for every $x$ in $\Bbb R$, now ask yourself: how could the sum of $2$ positive numbers lead to $-1$?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, not as simple and short as others:

Calculate the discriminant of the bi-quadratic and then apply the quadratic formula:

$$\Delta=7^2-4\cdot 2\cdot 1=41\implies x^2_{1,2}=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{41}
}8$$

and since $\;-7\pm\sqrt{41}<0\;$ there can't be real roots.

Comment: "... without doing calculation."

Comment: "...this is without finding the roots of the equation", as written there. Without *any* calculation I'd say it's almost impossible since even remarking that even powers of real numbers are non-negative implies calculations a priori, and after all this is mathematics, not mental exercises on kung-fu.